# Date range between datetime and datetime not picking up all rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

The code below is part of a procedure that directs our internal archive tool to archive a section of a table given a data date field range. Below I am directing it to archive any row with a data date field that is less than or equal to the 2019-12-31 date. Out of 22 million rows, there are about 1100 left that can't be picked up for some reason. These rows have a valid data date time that fits the range below. The tool works perfectly with all other 7 tables I tested it with but I am now stuck on this table where I can't seem to get it to pick up these valid rows. Any suggestions?

summary: code below can't detect 1k out of 22 million rows that validly fit the range

```
,REPLACE(SelectCSV,'BETWEEN ''@MinDataDate'' AND ''@MaxDataDate''','<=''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), '2019-12-31 23:59:59', 121) + '''')
```

Comment: Could you provide the min & max datetime values from the range of rows that are being ignored by the code and the exact data type of the date field?

Comment: Try 120 instead of 121 if there are no milliseconds to replace. And ensure that the rows left out have no trailing milliseconds. Alternatively replace "<=" with "<" and the next day, e.g. 2020-01-01( 00:00:00.000) to eliminate rows with milliseconds.